# How do I read the contents of a file and store it in a database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I need to read a file by column and store it in a database. My problem is the file contents are not stored in the database and the code just reads the contents. I am getting an error in storing it.

**Code:**

```java
public class Test3 {

    private static String vrms;
    private static String irms;
    private static String total;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "";

            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection not established");
            return null;
        }   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fstream = new 
        FileInputStream("D:/data/database.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strLine.split(" ");
            System.out.println(strLine);
        } 
        in.close();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            File file = new File(strLine);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into meter1(vrms, irms, total) values (?, ?, ?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, vrms);
            pstmt.setString(2, irms);
            pstmt.setString(3, total);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            pstmt.close();
            fis.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
10 11 0
12 13 0
14 15 0
Connection Established
Error: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at vidhya.Test3.main(Test3.java:71)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at vidhya.Test3.main(Test3.java:85)
```

Comment: Try to Indent the code. It's difficult to undersrand.

Comment: Please format your code in a readable manner.

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan *Indent* :)

Comment: @m0skit0 : Type, corrected

Comment: The error message/exception type would be helpful. And the type of the table columns.

Comment: perhaps you should store your data inside the while loop?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan *Typo* :)

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Btw, you split line is doing nothing. `String#split` returns a `String[]` and you're not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample code which might be helpful..
Replace the column names with correct db columns.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;


try{
    String read=null;
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patientlist.txt")); 
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
        name=splited[0];
        age=splited[1];
        height=splited[2];
        weight=splited[3];      
        addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);
    }

}
catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);}
    if (connection != null)
    try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore){} 
}


public static void addpatient(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedstatement, String name, String age, String height, String weight) throws SQLException{
preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into allpatients(name, age, height, weight) values(?,?,?,?)");
preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
preparedstatement.executeUpdate();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not stored information read from the file in any variable (vrms, irms or total). Correct your code before posting here for the issue.

Posting the sample data file and column data types will be helpful.